# World colour is creating some fog like effect in eevee

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, lighting, world

I've been using blender internal for most of my projects. I got a project done in internal into EEVEE and the world colour created some fog like effect on the screen depicted below:

[image]

The weird thing is Im pretty sure I solved this issue when I encountered it during the beta but I cant remember how, for reference heres a similar version of the image above that I did in during the beta:

[image]

How do I get rid of this foggy effect thats most likely caused by the world background colour?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, all I had to do was remove/disconnect volumetric scatter in the world tab.